# Unable to change object values on successful ping

Tags: powershell, replace

I am trying to replace variables in my table but I can't seem to do it. On a successful ping, I want the value under `Success` to be changed to a 1, but no matter what I do it stays a 0. `$ping` currently returns something like this:

```
+-------------------+----------+
|     Hostname      |  Success |
+-------------------+----------+
| BVL-W71455781745  |        0 |
| BVL-WX966103545   |        0 |
| BVL-W7583554017   |        0 |
+-------------------+----------+
```

```
$ping = Import-csv C:\temp\pingtst.csv -Header 'Hostname' | Select-object *,@{Name='Success';Expression={'0'}}
$i = 0
foreach ($HostName in $ping.Hostname) {

if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $HostName -count 3 -Quiet)
    {
        $ping.Success[$i] = '1'
        $i = ($i + 1)
        } else

        {$ping.Success[$i] = '0'
        $i = ($i + 1)
        }
        }
```

Comment: You should blame "member enumeration" (PowerShell v3+ feature) that it at all allows you to write `$ping.Hostname` or `$ping.Success`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are iterating over your objects in a peculiar fashion. Also you are not indexing your array on the correct element. I do not have a technical explanation yet but when you index on Success like so

> ```
> $ping.Success[$i]
> ```

That does *return* the correct value for the correct row. However you do not have direct access to *set* a value on that row. Your default value of 0 stays in that case.

If you instead did something like this you would get the result you were expecting.

```
$ping[$i].Success
```

The whole `$i` is not required either as there is a much better way to work through your object array.

```
$results = Import-csv C:\temp\pingtst.csv -Header 'Hostname' | 
    Select-object hostname,@{Name='Success';Expression={'0'}} | 
    ForEach-Object{
        # Test the connection. Since the value is already 0 only change on success
        if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_.Hostname -count 3 -Quiet){
            $_.Success = 1
        }
        # Send this row down the pipeline
        $_


}

# This should look like you expect now.
$results
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. Im new to powershell and coding in general so my way of doing things is... different. I appreciate your help!